# Redux action with parameter vs multiple actions

Tags: redux, reswift

What's the recommended way for actions of an API request cycle?

i.e.: I usually have 3 steps

- request started (waiting on response)
- request finished successfully (and returned a value)
- request failed (or returned an error)

I can model those steps as 3 actions

- `RequestDidStartAction`
- `RequestDidFinishWithSuccessAction` (here I'd have the value as a property of the action)
- `RequestDidFinishWithFailureAction` (here I'd have the error as a property of the action)

Or I could model it as one action that has an enum:

```
struct RequestAction: Action {

    let state: AsyncRequestState<Value, Error>

}

enum AsyncRequestState<S, F> {

    case waiting
    case success(S)
    case failure(F)

}
```

Which of the two ways is better? Or is there an even better option?

Ps.: I'm using ReSwift, but I think the question applies to any Redux implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion and from what I have read, the first implementation is the right way of doing it.

***Actions are payloads of information that send data from your application to your store. They are the only source of information for the store***

source: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html

From philosophical point of view as an action is entailed as a payload of information meant for store, it is of importance to distinguish different payloads easily. From usage point of view it can be a nested data set which you can parse anytime you require to check the action again.

Example use case of this comes in UNDO, when you perform a delete action, and you want to undo that action it will be great help if ACTIONS are diverse. As it helps to identify what action to be reversed. Consider a multiple API call happening at same time, now you have to keep track of what action it is and which API call it is as well, so its better you keep the actions separate so that the complications of checking type from a nested data structure doesn't arise.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, could you show me an example where the first model is better than the second?

Comment: hope this helps https://github.com/acdlite/flux-standard-action this is a standard created by community.